# Why do the Golden State Warriors call themselves dubnation?

Tags: basketball, terminology

The basketball team *The Golden State Warriors* call themselves dubnation.
Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dub = short for W

W = Warriors

Different way of saying Warriornation.